# Data Validation field properties from Macro

Tags: vba, excel, validation

Is there a way we can retrieve various properties of fields present in Data Validation Window from an excel macro code?

Please see below screenshots for a reference:

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

As seen in above screenshots can I get the highlighted values from inside a macro code?

Comment: Couldn't you just do it for one example, record it in an macro, while doing so and look at the code?

Comment: @MarcoGetrost : It worked for me by recording a macro. Thanks. I didn't knew about this feature before